# Angular - i18n uses

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-elements

I want use the same label rendering different string depending on which user I use.

e.g:

For user 1:

```
<h1>Hello I am the user 1</h1>
```

For user 2:

```
<h1>What's up user 2?</h1>
```

I don't want use conditionals or so(maybe a .json? I don't know). It is a big project so I need something consistent.

Any idea?

Comment: What condition determines what should be shown? How many conditions might you have? How many places do you want to have conditional text? There is a lot of information that you could add to your question that would help clarify the requirements.

Comment: @KurtHamilton I have to add a lot of different content to 31 different clients. This is just a quick example.

Comment: Well this is maybe bad example then?

Comment: @Antoniossss I think it is a clear example. I just added a simple html header to do a quick example but, obviously, I am going to have a lot of labels with a lot of strings as body, footer, different popups, etc. Like I said it is a big project.

Comment: Isn't it easier to get this data from the backend depending on the user? Assuming each user has a customized greeting message that will not change. However, if you want a random greeting message for each user from a list of greeting messages I think you need to edit your question for more clarity.

Comment: It's not necessarily related to i18n, is it? You would have the same problem if all your users were using the same language.

Answer (score -1):

You can delegate that to the component controller like this

```
<h1>{{userSpecificGreeting}}</h1>
```

and in component code

```
get String userSpecificGreeting(){
    return this.getUserSpecificGreetingSomehow(this.currentUser); //do it here or delegate to a shared service
}
```

And if I understand your unclear comment maybe it would be good to encapsulate that as a separate component, pipe or directive so such greetings will be available for other componetns to use